Executing a function after ten minutes the user closes the website
is it possible to execute a function ten minutes after a user closes the website? I am using Nextjs v14 and deploying the project to Vercel and I am triggering the function with an window.addEventListener(onClose, callback) the callback is a server action and has a timer inside that is set to 10 minutes until the body of the function is executed. I have tested out if this is working and it is working in my local enviroment, but when I deploy to vercel, it does not work anymore. Why is this? What options do I have to do this with a hobby account?
I guess it has something to do with the max duration of function in the vercel deployment?
